# Change for cross function from R2019a to R2019b

Tags: matlab

I see that to perform the calculation done by R2019a's cross function I now have to do conj(cross). I see that https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cross.html has been updated, but where else is this notable change documented ?

(I asked the question at https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/491760-change-for-cross-function-from-r2019a-to-r2019b but I think that it deserves also visibilty here, as the change is really notable.)

Comment: Previously the behavior for complex numbers was not documented: https://de.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2019a/matlab/ref/cross.html

Comment: This is not documented in the [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=cross&startrelease=R2019b&endrelease=R2019b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=cross).

Comment: I know, but I wanted to be sure. ;) It just took me 2h of "parallel" 2019a vs 2019b debugging to realize they've change that.

Comment: That sucks. Changes like this should certainly be mentioned in the release notes. At the bottom of the release notes page there is a box that asks "How useful was this information?". I suggest you rate the page there, and in the following question tell them that this is a major change in behavior that should have been documented. :)

Comment: Honestly I am not very inclined to a dialogue with them. I posted there to be square, but they seem to statistically answer to users with licence only, even when licenceless users ask important questions as I already asked in the past ... But I'll guess I'll do it nevertheless as it could help other users ...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the `cross.m` function was changed from R2019a ⇒ R2019b: the wrapping of cross products with `conj()` on lines 33-35 and 65-67.

As noted in a comment on the question, this change was **not documented** as part of the release notes (neither on the [help portal](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=cross&startrelease=2019b&endrelease=R2019b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=cross) nor in the [PDF version](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/rn.pdf)).

Seeing how changes impacting backward/forward compatibility are typically marked with "Functionality being removed or changed ⚠️", the fact this change is undocumented can only be attributed to **oversight**, aka "a documentation bug".